# Ansible: print list of files that will be copied

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that copy files from different local folders to different remote paths and it works, configured to overwrite the files with backup (with copy module).
How to get the list of files that will be copied and overwrite before doing it?
I'd like to prevent to copy wrong files.

Example of the copy:

```
name: Copy all
copy:
  src: scenarios/all_machines/
  dest: /path/to/dest
  backup: yes
  force: yes
  owner: root
  group: root
  mode: 0644
when: ansible_facts.services['crowdsec.service'] is defined
```

**************UPDATE**************

With this local folder:

```
scenarios/all_machines/
├── wg-sshd-more-logs.yaml
└── wg-x00.yaml
```

and this remote dir:

```
test_ansible/
└── wg-x00.yaml
```

where the wg-x00.yaml file has the same content.

With this playbook (where I changed the '>' char with '<'):

```
- name: TEST
    synchronize:
      src: scenarios/all_machines/
      dest: test_ansible/
      rsync_opts:
        - --dry-run
    register: result

  - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines

  - name: TEST 2
    set_fact:
      overwrite: "{{ file_stat|
                     selectattr('stat', 'match', '<f.*')|
                     selectattr('stat', 'ne', '<f+++++++++')|
                     map(attribute='file')|
                     list }}"
    vars:
      file_stat: "{{ result.stdout_lines|
                     map('regex_replace', regex, replace)|
                     map('from_yaml')|
                     list }}"
      regex: '^(.*?) (.*)$'
      replace: '{file: "\2", stat: "\1"}'

  - debug:
      var: overwrite
```

I have this output:

```
"result.stdout_lines": [
        ".d..tp..... ./", 
        "<f+++++++++ wg-sshd-more-logs.yaml", 
        "<f..tp..... wg-x00.yaml"
    ]



"overwrite": [
        "wg-x00.yaml"
    ]
```

So:

- I changed the the '>' char with '<' because my output is different from your
- The overwrite variable tells me that the file will be overwritten but they are equal...

Answer (score 1):

Given the directories below for testing

```sh
shell> tree scenarios/all_machines/
scenarios/all_machines/
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

0 directories, 3 files
```

```sh
shell> tree dest/
dest/
└── file1

0 directories, 1 file
```

the file *file1* at *dest/* will be replaced. The question is how to find it.

Use [*synchronize*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#ansible-posix-synchronize-a-wrapper-around-rsync-to-make-common-tasks-in-your-playbooks-quick-and-easy) and set 'rsync_opts: --dry-run'

```yaml
    - synchronize:
        src: scenarios/all_machines/
        dest: dest
        rsync_opts:
          - --dry-run
      register: result
```

The *result* will display the status of the files

```yaml
  result.stdout_lines:
    - .d..t...... ./
    - '>f..t...... file1'
    - '>f+++++++++ file2'
    - '>f+++++++++ file3'
```

The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        overwrite: "{{ file_stat|
                       selectattr('stat', 'match', '>f.*')|
                       selectattr('stat', 'ne', '>f+++++++++')|
                       map(attribute='file')|
                       list }}"
      vars:
        file_stat: "{{ result.stdout_lines|
                       map('regex_replace', regex, replace)|
                       map('from_yaml')|
                       list }}"
        regex: '^(.*?) (.*)$'
        replace: '{file: "\2", stat: "\1"}'
```

will create the list

```yaml
  file_stat:
    - {file: ./, stat: .d..t......}
    - {file: file1, stat: '>f..t......'}
    - {file: file2, stat: '>f+++++++++'}
    - {file: file3, stat: '>f+++++++++'}
```

and will select names of the existing files only

```yaml
  overwrite:
    - file1
```

See [Understanding the output of rsync --itemize-changes](http://www.staroceans.org/e-book/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html).

---

**Notes**

- Use [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#ansible-builtin-debug-print-statements-during-execution) to display the variables. For example, use [to_yaml/to_nice_yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) filters

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: file_stat|to_yaml
```

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: overwrite|to_nice_yaml
```

- Use [yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#community-general-yaml-yaml-ized-ansible-screen-output) callback.
- See [DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback) on how to configure the callback.

Comment: really interesting answer..i didnt know this functionality

Comment: See [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#ansible-builtin-debug-print-statements-during-execution). Use [yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html#community-general-yaml-yaml-ized-ansible-screen-output). Set [DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback).

Comment: @drugo, see [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Delete the comments. Instead [edit] the question to make it [mre].